# How to place an If/Else statement in a where clause in a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

How would I place an if else in this linq statement?

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString()
```

I would like to do something like

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == if(royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString().Length == 3) "0" + royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString() else royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString()
```

I think something similar can be done when using lambda expressions but my query doesn't and not sure how to convert my query to use nothing but lambda expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) or ternary conditional operator (?:)

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == 
    (royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString().Length == 3
    ? "0" + royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString()
    : royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString())
```

Alternatively, use the PadLeft function

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')
```

or simply (assuming RoyalIns is an integer type)

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString("0000")
```

Comment: I get an error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type string and bool

Comment: Try putting in extra brackets, the operator precedence may be unintuitive

Comment: I removed the bracket from the right side of the 3 and placed the bracket at the end

Comment: Note that the second option may work for more cases in general, e.g. for numbers < 100

Comment: Thanks for the answers and explanations

Answer (score 3):

Using [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
where instruct.InstructorInstrNo == ((royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString().Length == 3) ? 
                                   "0" + royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString() : royalHIstory.RoyalIns.ToString())
```

From the docs:

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on
>   the value of a Boolean expression.